# How to retrieve my roles that are stored in database as enums?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, enums

I'm using enum for roles, I have like admin, user roles and they are saved in database as numbers 0 for admin, 1 for user. Now I want to retrieve these numbers in the frontend using React to make the dashboard valid only for the admin role.

```
namespace WebApi.Entities
{
    public enum Role
    {
        Admin,
        User
    }
}
```

This is the backend part.

```
export const Role = {
    Admin: 'Admin',
    User: 'User'
}
```

The frontend part that I'm trying to use but this doesn't work. Also changing the Admin and User to 0 and 1 doesn't work.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentUser: null,
            isAdmin: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => this.setState({
            currentUser: x,
            isAdmin: x && x.role === Role.Admin
        }));
    }

    logout() {
        authenticationService.logout();
        history.push('/login');
    }

    render() {
        const { currentUser, isAdmin} = this.state;
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    {currentUser &&
                        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
                            <div className="navbar-nav">
                                <Link to="/" className="nav-item nav-link">Home</Link>
                                <Link to="/users" className="nav-item nav-link">Users</Link>
                                {isAdmin&& <Link to="/admin" className="nav-item nav-link">Admin</Link>}
                                <a onClick={this.logout} className="nav-item nav-link">Logout</a>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    }
                    <div className="jumbotron">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/users" component={Users} />
                                    <PrivateRoute path="/admin" roles={[Role.Admin]} component={AdminPage} />
                                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Error: x is not defined [for console.log(x.role)]

This is the part in App.jsx that I'm using for dashboard to be valid only to Admin.

I know the solution to change my backend from enum to string so that the roles would be stored as string in database, but I want to be able to convert this as it is.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 & React.Js

Comment: in your role enum did u tried specifying Admin = 1 ?

Comment: There is no need for that because I have like 5 admins created they all have the role 0 same goes for users.

Comment: `console.log` `x.role` and `Role.Admin` and compare the outputs

Comment: Role.Admin shows text "Admin" and the x.role can't show it on console.log I get errors (I updated the code of app.jsx to see where I put the console.log and also the error about x.role) Ps. If someone could contact me thru email rastrast3443@gmail.com so I could share the code with him and show all the details, I hope I'm not breaking any policy for sharing my email).

Comment: in your role enum I'm thinking of specifying Admin = 1  so that when you are fetching roles from dB they are mapped correctly. If in this way its working then I can understand the struggle.

Comment: That didn't work. Also, I tried changing the enums to strings, but apparently, that didn't work also. (Check the code I added more)